# How to find Images In mysql Database Column?

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have an art blog where I upload images that I have been working on.

Now what I would like to do is when a user is browsing through my articles they are shown a short summary of the article before viewing it (like a thumbnail for an image). With that said I would like to retrieve a few of the images which are used in the article and display them with the description view. Any Ideas as to the best means of performing this task?

My articles are kept in an article database table the main content is filed under the column of body and the articles are saved with htmlentities

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion/knowledge MySQL does not have any added functionality for querying images.
It is possible to store an Image inside a Database as a Blob with PHP.

However, there are many non-believers (including me) for this kind of operation.
I would rather (because the Database is MySQL) only store the path to the images.

Other Databases like those of Oracle (with interMedia) have extra usefull functionality for images.